# Get the product categories and display it on cart page woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display the categories of each product on a cart page. I have not much knowledge of php. I am using this code:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
   $product_cat = $term->name;
}
echo $product_cat ;
```

To test this code I put in one `<div>` in the `woocommerce/cart/cart.php` just under the `foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item )` loop and it worked, but it shows me only the last category of each products, not all categories.

I would like to show all the categories, and not in the beginning of the page but just after the shipping info before the sub-total and the total.

I tried to put this code in the `cart-totals.php` in a new `<tr><th>Some Title</th><td>[PHP Code here]</td></tr>` but it showed nothing as a result. I thinks that its because the code goes out from the `foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item )`. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

[EDIT]

I don't know if this is the best way to do it but this code seems to work in the `cart-total.php`

```
<?php
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) { 

$_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); 

$product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

$terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
$product_cat = array();

foreach ($terms as $term) {
   $product_cat[] .= $term->name;
}

echo implode(', ', $product_cat);

?>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: In your foreach loop, you overwrite the $product_cat variable each time the loop runs, that is why you only see the last category.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I remedy that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
$product_cat = array();

foreach ($terms as $term) {
   $product_cat[] .= $term->name;
}

echo implode(', ', $product_cat);
```

This will put all your categories in an array, and you can implode it to output it as a string separated by a comma.